# Did Finwe take up the Kingship of the Noldor again?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

We know that Finwe was slain by Melkor by the gates of Formenos as the Silmarils were stolen. Then Feanor rebelled (and stuff happened here) and Finarfin became King of the Noldor in Valinor.

Finwe would presumably have gone to the halls of Mandos for a time of reflection.

Was he then reborn into Valinor as described with Finrod? I know Feanor was doomed to spend eternity in Mandos for his actions but Finwe did nothing against the Valar.

If indeed he was reborn, did he retake the kingship?

In the same vain, would Fingolfin have taken the kingship back from Finarfin when he was reborn (as he had the greater claim).

Otherwise Finwe would presumably be subject to his son, even though he is one of the most senior of the Eldar.

I also remember something about Finwe holding himself "Unkinged" while Feanor was banished which may explain why he may not take up the kingship again, however this doesn't apply to Fingolfin.

(P.S. I know elves are not "reborn" I am using the term instead of "Reembodied or Embodified" :-))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, he didn't.

The latter history of Finwe and Miriel, recounted in *Morgoth's Ring*, tells that after Finwe was slain Miriel regretted of her choice, and - because bigamy was unlawful for the Eldar - Finwe was (voluntarily) kept in Mandos forever whereas Miriel was released.

> Therefore when Nienna came to him and renewed her prayer for Miriel, he consented, accepting the abnegation of Finwe as her ransom. Then the fea of Miriel was released and came before Manwe and received his blessing; and she went then to Lorien and re-entered her body, and awoke again, as one that cometh out of a deep sleep; and she arose and her body was refreshed.

This material was never rejected by JRRT but was significantly cut by CT for the published *Silmarillion*.

Regarding Fingolfin and Finarfin, the only mention of this I'm aware of is that Finarfin still led the Noldor at the time of the War of Wrath (quoted from the *Silmarillion*):

> ...beneath their white banners marched the Vanyar, the people of Ingwe, and those also of the Noldor who never departed from Valinor, whose leader was Finarfin the son of Finwe.

I'm not aware of anything concerning the release (or not) of Fingolfin from Mandos, and what the relations are, beyond that point in time.

Comment: Thats interesting, I hadnt read that source, So essentialy Finwe was holding to his original vow to be unkinged while feanor was still banished/imprisoned. I always found the quote about Finrod walking in Valinor with his father interesting, and they say that most of the Noldor were forgiven, and given Fingolfins heroic battle against Morgoth it is possible I suppose that this could count in the same vain as Finrod sacrificing himself for Beren, and therefore would be reborn as Finrod.It just seems odd if he didnt take up the kingship as he seemed to be the most popular and wise of Finwes sons

Comment: (Re: Fingolfin) There's no source to say that he didn't, just as there's no source to say that he did.  My reading of Fingolfin's battle is that he had given into despair, and that - despite his obvious heroism - by fighting Morgoth he had effectively "committed suicide", which I don't imagine would bode well for an early release.

Comment: (Re: Finwe) His voluntary remaining in Mandos wasn't connected to Feanor; it was pity for Miriel: "*But it is
better still that thou hast made this offer, to deprive thyself, of thy free will, and out of pity for another*".

Answer (score 0):

I think Finarfin would be king, cause Finwe would stay in Mandos. Fingolfin decided to leave Aman and so imho forsook the right to be king there, that would belong to Finarfin and after all it is the land of the Valar and I think in the mind of the Valar Finarfin is more worthy, cause he never rebelled.
And the most wise of Finwes children was Finarfin, not Fingolfin.

Comment: That more of less summarises what actually happened, but the "I think" stuff is not appropriate for an answer on this site.  Answers shouldn't be fan theory, they should be verifiable from the source works.